# How yank external output to windows clipboard in vim

Tags: vim

I need to the ouput html from external pandoc yanked to windows clipboard.
Using this expression

`:let @+ = %!pandoc -f markdown -t html`

results in error *E15: invalid expression:%!pandoc -f markdown -t html*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the output of the shell command to be saved in the register, not the command itself that in this case is also not recognised as a valid expression.

Try

```
:let @+ = system('pandoc -f markdown -t html')
```

the system() function gets the output of the shell command as a string and should do exactly what you wanted

To apply the command to the file in the current buffer you can use the "expand" function to append the file name to the command:

```
:let @+ = system('pandoc -f markdown -t html ' . expand("%"))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue @pappix. Trying your suggestion results in a cmd that stays open  


`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (pandoc -f markdown -t html ^>C:\Users\PP\AppData\Local\Temp\VIoF94E.tmp 2^>^&1)` 


and nothing in clipboard. Any ideas left?

Comment: Have you tried with a different command? I tested it on linux system issuing as command 'ls' (list dir) and it worked for me (I don't have pandoc). Now I am not sure why it is not working but I would guess it might be an issue with the particular command you are trying to issue.
Is what you posted the output you see on screen? 
have you tried to just hit enter and se if the cmd closes and gets you back to vim?
Is the command you are issuing any different from `pandoc -f markdown -t html`?

Comment: If you meant to apply the command to the current file in the buffer you can append the file name using "expand" like below:

`:let @+ = system('pandoc -f markdown -t html ' . expand("%"))`

updated the answer to include this additional detail

Comment: Thank you very much @pappix :)